# (edit) Brushless Motor - Why does the stator burn up if the rotor doesn't rotate?

Tags: motor, rotor, stator

If I was to apply power to a 3 phase stator, which in turn creates a magnetic field that's projected onto the rotor (with magnets), and (in a friction-less world) would cause the rotor to rotate (bearings on the forward and aft of the rotor).

If the rotor was to become jammed/stuck/no longer able to spin, why does the stator burn up? Wouldn't the magnetic field continue to be applied to the rotor?

I apologize if the specific terms are incorrect. I'm mainly trying to understand why the stator becomes damaged if the rotor is unable to spin. Obviously there's no physical damage between the stator/rotor (rubbing,ect).

Answer (score 7):

This answer was given prior to the op changing the question. Originally, the question referred to the motor as being a squirrel cage type. Subsequently, after several comments, the op changed it to a brushless motor. You just can’t get the staff any more!

When you stall a 3 phase motor it becomes a transformer and, because the rotor is the secondary AND is shorted out (by necessity for it to operate as a motor), you end up with a shorted transformer.

Ask yourself why a transformer burns when the secondary is shorted.

Comment: OP referred to the stator burning up rather than the rotor. This could be OP just not knowing which but has failed; but might be worth addressing nevertheless.

Comment: Yes. I am referring to the stator burning up because the rotor doesn't rotate. For instance, a locked rotor test.

Comment: @Luke If you short out a transformer secondary which has a sufficiently thick wire, the primary coil burns out. In this case the rotor is a very thick wire.

Comment: But we aren't shorting the rotor to anything? I'm only preventing it from moving.

Comment: @Luke the rotor is shorted out as part of the construction of the motor. It is shorted because if it wasn’t, it wouldn’t produce a magnetic field when the stator is activated. Just look at the construction of the squirrel cage and ask yourself how it isn’t self shorting by design. So, voltage is induced in the rotor and, the sorting causes a current to flow.

Comment: I was incorrect with Squirrel cage. It is a brushless motor. The rotor has magnets.. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

The induction motor generates the currents in the rotor by induction (hence the obvious name), these currents then generate torque by interaction with field generated by the stator. The magnitude of the emf generated in the rotor is dependent on the frequency it sees - the difference between the speed it is rotating at and the speed the rotating field generated by the stator - this is the 'slip' usually expressed as a proportion of the synchronous speed.

The frequency is therefore at its highest when the rotor is stationary, though the induced current isn't necessarily at its highest, since the rotor winding (the squirrel cage in this case) has inductance that limits the current, but in any case, the rotor current generates its own field, that opposes the main field, reducing the back emf at the stator windings, so that the current through them also rises.

[image]

The stator current is therefore at its highest at locked rotor. Even without the loss of cooling that you get from the rotor spinning, the stator will be hottest like this.